# Parsing Json Files in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swift3, xcode8

I would like to parse a local JSON file but I am unaware of how to do so in Swift 3

My Current Code doesn't seem to work

I keep receiving this error:

> 'jsonObject' produces 'Any', not the expected contextual result type 'NSArray'

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    var allEntries: String!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func LoadAllQuestionsAndAnswers
    {
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "content", ofType: "json")
            let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
            allEntries = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil) as String
            NSLog(allEntries)
    }

}
```

I am loading the data from this json file "content.json"

```
[
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "question": "What is the fastest fish in the ocean?",
             "answers": [
             "Sailfish",
             "Lion Fish",
             "Flounder",
             "Tiger Shark",
             "Swordfish"
            ],
         "difficulty": "1"
     },
     {
         "id" : "2",
         "question": "Which animal has the most legs?",
              "answers": [
              "Millipede",
              "Shrimp",
              "Octopus",
              "Dog",
              "Lion"
            ],
          "difficulty": "1"
     }
]
```

Comment: The code you have use doesn't even compile because from Swift 2 there is no parameter like error with this method instead you need to throw it using try catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root object of the JSON is an array

```
var allEntries = [[String:Any]]()
...
allEntries = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]
```

`mutableContainers` is not needed at all in Swift

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this and it was throwing me an arrow, I used `[String:Any]` instead of `[[String:Any]]` and I was able to get the return

Answer (score 3):

```
let path =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "son")
 let jsonData = try? NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe) 
print(jsonData!) 
let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData as! Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

// save below sample json in a file and name it as sample.json

> {
>       "blogs": [
>                 {
>                 "id": 111,
>                 "url": "http://roadfiresoftware.com/blog/",
>                 "name": "Roadfire Software Blog"
>                 },
>                 {
>                 "id": 345,
>                 "url": "https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/",
>                 "name": "Swift Developer Blog"
>                 }
>                 ]
>   }